# How to proccess a login form with htmx?

Tags: javascript, ajax, htmx

I want to post to `/login` with email and password, **then do things with the result (token and so in)**

```
<form hx-post="/login">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="text" name="password" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I tried adding this `hx-trigger="click[proccess(THIS_DOES_HAVE_ANYTHING)]` but `proccess()` would not have access to the results

---

I know we can do this

```
<button
  hx-get="https://v2.jokeapi.dev/joke/Any?format=txt&safe-mode"
  hx-target="#output"
>Click Me</button>

<div id="output"></div>
```

But, I need something like `hx-target=" proccess() "` but doesn't work

Comment: I think it is worth mention that in spirit of htmx fundamentals, cookie based authentication  is more fit as it requires zero or minimal javascript on the client

Answer (score 3):

`hx-target` is for receiving hypermedia response. if you want your client JS function to process something from the response, you can add a custom event listener to the document body and then send an `HX-Trigger` header in the response to call the listener.
https://htmx.org/headers/hx-trigger/